# Custom Django MultilingualTextField model field

Tags: python, django, django-models, multilingual

I'm trying to create Multilingual text field in Django for my project. I use JSON to store translated text in database and write custom code in field to retrieve it in the right language. For example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   text = MultilingualTextField(default_language="en")


mymodel = MyModel.objects.create(text="Welcome")
mymodel.text.val('fr','Bienvenue')
#...
mymodel.save()
```

when store in database it become

```
{"en":"Welcome","fr":"Bienvenue","es":"Bienvenida"}
```

And we can call `model.text.val('es')` to have "Bienvenida".

I use json dumps and json loads for store and retrieve database value. My Question is: is this a good way to do this? Does anyone has better technique?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look [Django Model Translation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) . It doesn't store the data in json but rather creates different db columns for each language(ex. text_en, text_fr ..) which I think is better.

Comment: How can this better? If I want to add language later, I have to create another column?

Comment: Firstly it is better because access to data is easier because you do not have to json encode decode every time you get the field. If you have looked through the Model Translation Documentation you would have seen that you do not need to add fields manually. You just set which fields need to be translated and the fields are added automatically for all the languages registered in settings.py

Comment: Another benefit is that is working well with Django admin automatically adding different fields for every language.

Comment: I've created it, please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057168/django-multilingual-text-field-using-json